# Choosing k pairs l distance apart from n numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I need to choose $k$ pairs of numbers out of first $n$ natural numbers such that the elements in each pair are $l$ distance apart. For example, if $n = 10, k = 3$ and $l = 2$, $\{(1,3),(4,6),(7,9)\}$ is a valid choice. How many such valid choices are there? I worked out for $l = 1$ and it seems to be $\binom{n-k}{k}$.
Edit: I forgot to mention that no number can be repeated which means choosing $(1,2)$ and $(2,5)$ is not allowed because it has 2 in common. Also, the pairs are not ordered.
Edit2: I have received an answer to this question. Please refer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208994/choosing-k-pairs-l-distance-apart-from-n-numbers?noredirect=1#comment518072_208994

Comment: pairs or ordered pairs? E.g. $\{1,3\}=\{3,1\}$ but $(1,3)\neq(3,1)$. Are we dealing here with $1$ possibility or with $2$?

Comment: @drhab I am sorry for the misunderstanding. Please refer the edit.